# Close browser after 1min last keyboard aclivity and mouse activity

Tags: c#

I have created a browser using visual C# .i want it to close when client not using it.It have to be close after one min last activity happen. 
how to catch mouse activity and key board activity

Comment: Is the question: how do I close the window, how do I create the delay or how do I detect mouse or keyboard activity within my window (or some combination)? Also, is this WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/e66cd9b4-93a9-4c6d-b61a-06013981e3b0    refer this one it might fix your problem